# Selenium not loading custom chrome profile

Tags: python, selenium

Following is my code for loading a custom chrome profile, but its not working , its loading a new chrome session every time.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/home/avanti/.config/google-chrome/Profile 2")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('www.google.com')
```

I have used 'chrome://version' to find out my user profile path.
Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: I don't know what effect you want. Can you give me an example?

Comment: @DanteVoronoi , I have saved passwords in this particular 'Profile 2' profile. When a new session of browser is created by selenium , I have to enter password everytime but if selenium is able to load my custom profile  I can skip entering the password

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-keep-the-session-after-login-with-Selenium-Python maybe something like here can help you

Comment: So, you want open old session after start your script?

Comment: You need to point new fresh folder location any where from your system.. first time it will create new session then it uses same profile...:)

Comment: @SaurabhGaur can you please explain a bit more